# CSS - dynamically calculate width for IE11 with out Jquery

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11, css-expressions

My application works fine in IE8, now we are migrating to IE11. Please find the div css below

```
.contentDiv{
  height:expression(document.body.clientHeight - contentDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top);
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Css expression has been depreciated now. Could you please suggest me how to calculate the dynamic div width height for IE11 and also it should work in IE8 also?

Comment: What is the purpose of the calculation? Are you maintaining an aspect ratio or placement of the div on the page?

Comment: This above Div Style is generic of all DIv in application. The purpose of calculation is for placement of div . and it should be using document.body.clientHeight - contentDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top.

Comment: I need your suggestion how to achieve it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery on the site (and you should) then you could have jQuery quickly cycle through the elements with that class and set the height explicitly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.contentDiv').each(function(){
        $(this).css('height',$(document).height() - $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().top);
    });
});
```

You'll want to keep the `overflow-y:scroll;` style definition in the CSS.